# What's wrong with joule thief circuit?

Tags: led, joule-thief

[image: circuit]

- Transistor 2n3904
- Homemade transformer with 10 turns
- Power supply 1.5 v

[Schematic:](https://graywolfsurvival.com/2491/the-joule-thief-a-preppers-best-friend-for-dead-or-homemade-batteries/)

[image]

I think the toroid winding shorts the power supply as it happens with my buck converter.

I think the toroid winding shorts the power supply as it happens with my buck converter.My multimeter shows the positive input and ground shorted,two of transformer are shorted and those are shorted with other outputs of transformer and one of them is connected to the ground

Comment: can't tell which LED lead is which from your photo.

Comment: what does it do/ not do? Where's your power sourcer attached? This is impossible to answer as is – aside from the solder joints looking *extremely* bad, we simply can't tell how your transistor and LED are connected. You have to draw a circuit *schematic* using the built-in schematic tool of this website's question editor to clarify what you're dooing.

Comment: Joule Thieves tend to rob power and kill batteries.  Winding polarity is critical  as well and turns ratio for base to collector load.

Comment: well i am powering it by 1.5v cell or a buck converter

Comment: i am afraid i think the toroid wing shorts the power supply

Comment: Your emitter is missing a battery connection.

Comment: @Jyotir, can you please share the image including battery..

Comment: Watch and learn how Julian makes a Joule-thief: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mik8hM5_hCI

Comment: sorry guys for making you a part of my idiotism now i corrected all mistakes and it works fine thank you all

Answer (score 1):

> I think the toroid winding shorts the power supply as it happens with my buck converter.

The toroid should not be connected so that it shorts the power supply.  If the red and black wires are going to the battery, then you've wired it wrong.  What you have in the photo doesn't match the circuit diagram.

I can only guess as to which lead from the transistor is which, but there should be no point where any wire from the toroid connects to the battery negative lead.

Comment: It looks a lot like the battery negative is connected to the transistor collector, instead of the emitter.